# Generating X,Y coordinates in Python for network graph in Tableau

Tags: python, networking, graph, tableau-api

Im looking to generate a set of X,Y coordinates to create from an already existing set of data. This result set should be able to be read in Tableau and thus should be formatted in this way (for example):

( http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/.a/6a00e554d9fb998833017c34841bd9970b-pi )

Where LineX, LineY and CircleY are the requirements. I would like to generate the X,Y coordinates according to algorithms (Fruchterman-Reingold) for example.
Is there any way to do this in Python?
I can show an example input set (from the real set) if necessary but I could format the set in any way, it's the process I need help with. I would like to have the result in dataframes or other table-form and eventually in CSV/sql server etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to create my own answer:

https://github.com/hammer-of-thor/NetworkGrapherTableau/blob/master/Network%20graph%20data.ipynb